# Meteor API call to Server

Tags: routes, meteor

I have a router.js set up that's accessible to both server and client. I then have a methods.js set up that's only on the server. I am trying to have the api call use the server's method, but router.js is not seeing the method at all: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'handleLoginAPI'`. How do I set this up correctly?

router.js

```
this.route('api-login', {
    where:'server',
    action: function() {
        var request = this.request;
        doSomething = function() {//send response}            
        Methods.handleLoginAPI(request, doSomething); 
    }
});
```

methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    handleLoginAPI: function(request, callback) {
        //check for valid user from request
        //login user
        //callback()
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the route to be server-side? Why then bother to write a method? If you already write a method, you can just leave the route client side.

Comment: The request is cross-site and coming from chrome extension js. As far as I am aware, I need that fielded on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) to call a method (or what is your `Methods`-object?).

Comment: Peppe, any idea how to then login the user? My problem here is that it's a cross-site request coming from a chrome extension, so that needs to go to the server, but then Meteor.loginWithPassword does not work on the server.

Comment: @user592419, Sorry, that area is pretty unknown for me.